# Legendre's equation of order n in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

The equation

$$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy'+n(n+1)y = 0$$

is called Legendre's equation of order $n$.

I need to show that this equation of order $1$ has $y=x$ as one solution and then I need to use this to find the general solution for $x$ greater than $-1$ but less than $1$ (not inclusive)

Comment: Did you try to take $n=1$ and plug in $y(x) = x$ and see if it satisfies the equation?

Comment: if i plug that in there is still a y''

Comment: and a y' in the equation

Comment: If $y(x) = x$ what is $y'(x)$ and $y''(x)$ ? In other words: what is the derivative of $x$ and the second derivative of $x$?

Comment: y'(x)=1   y''(x)=0

Comment: Then you know what to plug into the equation.

Comment: okay so the equation becomes (1-x^2)-2x+2x=0???

Comment: there i plugged in the values of y", y' and y

Comment: No it becomes $(1-x^2)\cdot \color{red}{0} - 2x\cdot \color{blue}{1} + 2\color{green}{x} = 0$. You forgot that $\color{red}{y''(x) = 0}$.

Comment: okay so then -2x+2x=0 which is true so then that verifies the equation?

Comment: Yes. That is enough to verify that $y(x) = x$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: ah yes i did sorry so then the first term will be 0

Comment: okay perfect that makes sense now thanks, so then the second part with the general solution for x greater than -1 but less than 1, (-1<x<1)  how do i go about varfying that

Comment: The next part is slightly more work as you must solve an ODE. One method that sometimes works is if you know a solution to an ODE, like here $y_1(x) = x$, then plugging in $y(x) = y_1(x) g(x) = x g(x)$ might helpt to give you a simpler ODE you can solve for $g(x)$ (and once you know $g$ you also know $y$). In this case this works (there might be simpler methods, but I can't think of a simpler one right now).

Comment: yeah we havent touched on this topic at all but now we need to know it for review for the exam

Comment: not sure how to complete that second part

Comment: You can start by trying to take $y(x) = x g(x)$, compute $y'(x)$ and $y''(x)$ and then insert them into the ODE and see what you get. If you don't see how to solve this ODE then feel free to ask.

Comment: so would y'(x)= g(x) + xg'(x) and y"= g'(x) + g'(x)+xg"(x)

Comment: okay then i will plug that it in and see where it gets me and i will write back in a few seconds

Comment: do i still assume n=1?

Comment: Yes this is the case you are asked to solve.

Comment: okay so i have (1-x^2)(2g'(x)+xg"(x)) - 2x(g(x)+xg'(x)) + 2xg(x)

Comment: so i guess i will expand everything out from here

Comment: Yes. This should lead to an equation on the form $g''(x) = a(x)g'(x)$. This equation is on the form $F'(x) = a(x) F(x)$ with $F(x) = g'(x)$. Such an equation has the solution $F(x) = e^{\int a(x) {\rm d}x}$ (try to compute $F'(x)$ to verify this). Thus you can find $g'(x) = e^{\int a(x) {\rm d}x}$ by solving the $a$-integral and simplifying. Computing the integral might require expanding in partial fractions and might seem a bit hard, but the results will be fairly simple in the end. Once you have this then one more integral is needed to find $g(x)$ by integrating $g'(x)$.

Comment: wow this is a lot of work lol

Comment: Solving ODEs is usually a lot of work. As I warned above there might be simpler ways here, but I don't see it right now (especially if we are to follow the same route as the hint given). Maybe someone else will come along with a better way. Anyway it's useful training in any case!

Comment: when i expanded and cancelled i got 2g'(x)+xg"(x)-x^3g"(x)

Comment: pretty sure i expanded and adding correctly

Comment: I get $x \left(1-x^2\right) g''(x)+\left(2-4 x^2\right) g'(x) = 0$ so I would double-check the calculations.

Comment: okay yes I see where i made my mistake

Comment: so they how do i go about solving that ODE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41995/discussion-between-winther-and-javahelp).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using power series.

\begin{equation}
 (1-x^2)y'' - 2xy'+n(n+1)y = 0
 \end{equation}
    Let $y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kx^k$, $y^\prime=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kc_kx^{k-1}$, $y^{\prime\prime}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(k-1)c_kx^{k-2}$

Then

\begin{equation}
 (1-x^2)\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(k-1)c_kx^{k-2}-2x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kc_kx^{k-1}+n(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kx^k=0
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(k-1)c_kx^{k-2}-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(k-1)c_kx^{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2kc_kx^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}n(n+1)c_kx^k=0
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2}x^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(k-1)c_kx^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2kc_kx^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}n(n+1)c_kx^k=0
  \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[(k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2}-k(k-1)c_k-2kc_k+n(n+1)c_k]x^k=0
\end{equation}

Therefore

\begin{equation}
(k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2}+(n(n+1)-k(k+1))c_k=0 \text{ for }k\ge0
\end{equation}

So
\begin{equation}
c_{k+2}=\frac{k(k+1)-n(n+1)}{(k+2)(k+1)}c_k
\end{equation}

Solving for the coefficients $c_k$ of the solution yields $c_2=-c_0, c_3=0$. Thus all odd powers of the series greater than $1$ will have coefficient zero and the general solution will be of the form
\begin{equation}
y=c_1x+c_0(1-x^2+\cdots)
\end{equation}

Therefore one linearly independent solution is $y_1=x$.

Comment: not sure if i can use power series or not but thanks for your time

Comment: I see that this is massive overkill. You only had to verify that $y=x$ is a solution and use reduction of order to find a second linearly independent solution. Nevermind.

Comment: yes do you know how to show that second part?

Comment: Here is a good youtube explanation of the process of "reduction of order" you can use to find a second solution to a second order DE given a first solution. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQSFW8BIrY0

Comment: What is liberaly independent solution and why is x fulfilling the condition?

Comment: @Abhinav For $n=1$ and $y=x$ we have $(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy'+n(n+1)y =(1-x^2)\cdot0- 2x\cdot1+1\cdot(2)x=0$.