# Reduction of order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to use the given solution y1 to find a second linearly independent solution

(X^2 -1)y" - 2xy' +2y = 0, y1 = x

So y = y1v => y = xv

y = xv

y' = v + xv'

y" = 2v' + xv"

From here I need to sub those into the equation and cancel down. However when it doesn't seem to work out. Just looking to get some help for my exam review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute your expressions into the DE, the $v$ terms cancel and you get
$$(x^3-x)v''-2v'=0\ .$$
Treating $v'$ as the new variable, this is a separable DE which gives
$$\ln(v')=\int\frac2{x^3-x}\,dx\ ,$$
and you should be able to do the integral by partial fractions to give eventually the answer
$$y=x^2+1\ .$$

Comment: Do I need make a subsitution for v"  for instance let v'=w then v"=w'

Comment: What is v'=?  How would I work out ln(v')

Comment: Sure, write a substitution if it helps.  Then do the integral.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of a question asked three hours ago. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848245/

Comment: Shouldn't there be a c value

Comment: Re: $c$ value: if you like.  But not necessary, since the question asked you to find *a second solution*, not *all possible solutions*.